# Where is ~ location on Android?

Tags: android, tasker

I am using Tasker to run a termux plugin. When I attempt to configure the sceduled task I am prompted with the following:

No ~/.termux/tasker/ directory. 
You need to create a ~/.termux/tasker/ directory containing scripts to be executed.

I have tried creating this folder in many locations (/data/, /data/data/, /storage/, ...) but have had no success in Tasker recognising any of them.

Where is ~ location on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adb shell` into the device, then `cd ~` and `pwd`... Should give some idea.

Comment: /data/data/com/termux/files/home

Thanks for the tip. I will remember that for next time! :)